# Translate open graph Facebook API with gender variations

Tags: facebook-graph-api, localization

I'm trying to translate my custom open graph action.

The problem is that in Portuguese is variation in sentence according to the "gender" of the object in question. I looked in the documentation and saw that I can translate differently according to "gender", but I did not find how to tell the gender of the object to Facebook.

I tried in various ways, creating an extra field in the object, sending information without the field, none of the ways the Facebook API identified, always entering the condition as if gender had not been informed, does anyone know how to solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem translating the "male" or "female" value for my native language.
My solution was this:

```
var getFacebookData = function(){
FB.api('/me?fields=gender,',function(response){
  if (response.gender === 'male'){
    var genero = 'Hombre'; // change the "male" value to other
  } else { // the "female" value to other
    var genero = 'Mujer'; 
  };
  $('#some_div_id').text('Sexo: '+ genero);
})};
```

I hope it helps, greetings.